# View missed branches with code coverage in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, code-coverage

I'm using the code coverage tool in Visual Studio 2015, and it's showing that some branches aren't being covered, but I can't find a way to view which branch specifically is being missed. While I can simply look at the unit tests and figure out which branch is being missed, is there a way to view the branches missed with the code coverage tool?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable Coverage colouring for your code.  In the window for Code Coverage, enable the button "Show Code Coverage Coloring"
[image]

Comment: I use this, but it overlays the coverage from each test, so a lot of sections are indistinguishable. Is there at least a way to see the coverage for individual tests, without having to rerun code coverage for each individual unit test?

Comment: As you say, you can see the individual coverage by running code coverage for each test individually. You can also see from the references how many unit tests are accessing this particular piece of code.  It is of course harder when you're deeper into the code, but then they should have their own tests.  Your original question was about missing code branches, and doesn't this solve this problem?  Also note that codelens indicates how many tests are testing this code.  I am not sure if you can get closer than this.  Also hard to see how that would look.  Any thoughts ?